# How add attribute with function to form which generates in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I have a code

```
FoxHtmlElem::create()->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('div')->attr('id', "fox-container-{$uid}")->classes('fox-container')->classes("fox-container-{$form->getScope()}")->classes($form->getParams()->get('pageclass_sfx'))->classes($form->getParams()->get('moduleclass_sfx'))->conditional($form->getParams()->get('show_page_heading', JComponentHelper::getParams('com_menus')->get('show_page_heading')), function () use($form)
{
    return FoxHtmlElem::create('h1')->text($form->getParams()->get('page_heading'));
})->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('a')->attr('id', "fox_{$uid}"))->conditional(!$board->getShowFormFields(), function ()
{
    return FoxFormRender::render('form_board');
})->conditional($board->getShowFormFields(), function () use($uid, $form)
{
    return FoxHtmlElem::create('form')->attr('name', "fox-form-{$uid}")->attr('action', JRoute::_('index.php'))->attr('method', 'post')->attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')->classes("fox-form fox-form-{$form->getDesign()->get('option.form.render')}")->append("<!-- Fox Contact [scope:{$form->getScope()}] [id:{$form->getId()}] [ver:{$form->getVersion()}] -->")->append(FoxFormRender::renders('row', $form->getDesign()->get('rows')))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'option')->attr('value', 'com_foxcontact'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'task')->attr('value', 'form.send'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'uid')->attr('value', $uid))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_uri')->attr('value', JUri::getInstance()))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_title')->attr('value', JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle()));
}))->show();
```

This code generates html

```
<div id="fox-container-m138" class="fox-container fox-container-module">
    <a id="fox_m138"></a>
    <form name="fox-form-m138" action="/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="fox-form fox-form-stacked">
        <!-- Fox Contact [scope:module] [id:138] [ver:3.6.0] -->
        <div class="fox-row">
            <div>...</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_foxcontact"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="task" value="form.send"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="m138"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="fox_form_page_uri" value="http://compmaster.su/index.php/?_ym_debug=1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="fox_form_page_title" value="Главная"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I need to add attribute to the form like this:

```
onsubmit="yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER', function () {
        alert('Date has been successfully sent');
    }, <The context is available for the keyword "this: inside the "callback-function">); return true;"
```

It is fox contact form for joomla.

Comment: You can add attribute onsubmit and call a function from javascript.

Comment: @MairajAhmad can you help me to do this? how the code must look like in attribute and in javascript?

Comment: Add another attribute in your php code like `>attr('onsubmit', "SubmitForm()")` and then in javascript write a function `SubmitForm` and put your code in this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another attribute `onsubmit` from your php code and call a `javascript function` on `onsubmit` and write yor code in `javascript function`.

```
>attr('onsubmit', "SubmitForm()")
```

Javascript code

```
function SubmitForm()
{
 //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the Below code

```
return FoxHtmlElem::create('form')->attr('name', "fox-form-{$uid}")->attr('action', JRoute::_('index.php'))->attr('method', 'post')->attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')->classes("fox-form fox-form-{$form->getDesign()->get('option.form.render')}")->append("<!-- Fox Contact [scope:{$form->getScope()}] [id:{$form->getId()}] [ver:{$form->getVersion()}] -->")->append(FoxFormRender::renders('row', $form->getDesign()->get('rows')))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'option')->attr('value', 'com_foxcontact'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'task')->attr('value', 'form.send'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'uid')->attr('value', $uid))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_uri')->attr('value', JUri::getInstance()))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_title')->attr('value', JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle()));
}))->show();
```

To

```
return FoxHtmlElem::create('form')->attr('name', "fox-form-{$uid}")->attr('action', JRoute::_('index.php'))->attr('method', 'post')->attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')->attr('onSubmit','yourJSCode')->classes("fox-form fox-form-{$form->getDesign()->get('option.form.render')}")->append("<!-- Fox Contact [scope:{$form->getScope()}] [id:{$form->getId()}] [ver:{$form->getVersion()}] -->")->append(FoxFormRender::renders('row', $form->getDesign()->get('rows')))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'option')->attr('value', 'com_foxcontact'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'task')->attr('value', 'form.send'))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'uid')->attr('value', $uid))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_uri')->attr('value', JUri::getInstance()))->append(FoxHtmlElem::create('input')->attr('type', 'hidden')->attr('name', 'fox_form_page_title')->attr('value', JFactory::getDocument()->getTitle()));
}))->show();
```

Then on the default.php page or where the tmpl file is there add the JS code like this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function yourJSCode(){  
       yaCounterXXXXXX.reachGoal('ORDER', function () {
        alert('Date has been successfully sent');
    }, <The context is available for the keyword "this: inside the "callback-function">); return true;
 }
</script>
```